# Workflow Approval - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: workflow, approval-process

I have got a problem with Workflow.

When I don't add a Approval Condition it's works great:

[image]

But When I add a Approve to workflow its not starting the workflow after Aproving element:

[image]

And the list is look like this, if Aoproval Workkflow is enable its dont work and don't pass the number of curent item and don't delete the element from another list:

[image]

Comment: I using Sharepoint 2010 workflow

Comment: so the mails dont get send? did you edit the default approval workflow?

Comment: eMail is sending, but the next workflow, which is on first screen, aren't run. I dont edit aproval workflow. I add new workflow. And it's not fire when the pending change to Approval.

Comment: what did you configure as start condition for your first workflow?

Comment: I'm worry that nothing. I tried to Write that whenIs changing from Pending to Approve it start another workflow.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can start another workflow if the first workflow is starting automatically (on change/update etc.)